# Spark SQL does not pick up changes in Hive table schema

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a Hive table that I wrote in Hive using Spark (`saveAs(tableName)`). Now I want to add a column to this table. My first approach was to add this column via Hive but apparently Spark does not pick up the new schema even though the column was added in the table. When I check table details in Hue, `spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0` is not updated. So I thought to add a column via Spark job that executes this query on the table. Same result, and the column is not even added in the table. Is there a way around this issue? I thought to change table name, create a new one with the right schema and then `insert select * ...` into new table but that didn't work as the tables are partitioned.

Comment: How were you adding a column in Spark? Specifically, have you tried running `ALTER TABLE...ADD COLUMNS` in Spark? And, what Spark version are you on?

Comment: yes thats what i did spark.sql("alter  table .. add columns").  i'am on spark 2.2.0

Comment: Check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21617

Comment: thanks. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21841 this one describes better my problem

Comment: Yeah, but that issue marked bulk-closed, probably because it was fixed along with the other one. Either way, upgrade to newer Spark version seems like a way to go.

Comment: yes you are right but i'am on production enviorement upgrading is not an option for now